# Best practice in storing class data in random access files

Tags: c++, class, struct, random-access, randomaccessfile

In C, data is typically organised in a `struct` data type. This is very convenient to save in a random access file, because you can just skip to the record you want using `sizeof` on the structure.

What is not clear to me what is the best approach to do this in C++, where you have a class with the data (together with some member functions which of course do not need to be persisted). Storing the class directly seems to be wrong, because of course this will include pointers to functions and that kind of stuff which is garbage once persisted to file.

Another approach I could think of is changing the member data inside the class, that needs to be persisted, to a `struct`, and change the accessor functions to look into the inner data structure. It seems to be a bit too intertwined but seems to be the only logical way to avoid replicating each field twice (once in a separate `struct` and once in the class).

This breaks down of course the moment you have inheritance, and the derived class adds new fields. Although this is hardly a problem specific to C++ and random access files, and its faced in many other Object Persistence approaches (including popular ORM packages in other programming languages) with [different possible strategies even when saving to a database table for instance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html).

Is there any 'defacto standard' approach people typically use in C++ to persist class data in files? Without having to replicate things all over the place?

Comment: No, there's no current serialization standard for c++. There are quite commonly used libraries like `boost::archive` or google protocol buffers though.

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for a standard as such though. Just what do people normally do if you have a class with some data and you need to save it to a file (and be able to look it up later). Do people just replicate everything?

Comment: Well, if you really need random access, even those libraries I mentioned aren't actually fitting. What you most probably want is a database storage.

Comment: I don't quite understand some parts in your question: class member functions are generally stateless, so they don't have to be persisted. You just need to store the objects data, same as for C structs.

Comment: And BTW just writing plain c structs to files, may have the same problems as well, like pointer fields, endianess issues, etc.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Well that depends on what the problem is and if you're writing some low level system which just needs to store some data in a file. My question is purely educational though. `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` offer `seekg` and `seekp` but I can't see any way to use them apart from with old C-style `struct`.

Comment: Sure, there isn`t any other way. It has it's pitfalls though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I know the pitfalls of C `struct` of course when you are persisting data (especially if its binary data rather than just strings). If a `struct` is designed to be persisted you obviously avoid pointers and other 'context dependence' so to speak.

Comment: @DanielStrul I never said I wanted to persist member functions, on the contrary I want to avoid saving the internal function pointers that a class stores. I am just asking what is the typical approach people use for this, without replicating all fields in a separate `struct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: it depends

Medium answer: it depends just the same in C struct can be directly serializable or not.

Long answer: If a class `A` is just Plain Old Data, it will be serializable as you could do with a C struct, that is binary copy and load `sizeof(A)` bytes. A class is a POD object if it contains only primitive type members or arrays of them, and/or subobjects that are POD themselves. It can have methods or static methods, but **no virtual** methods (not even a virtual destructor).

For example char arrays are acceptable, but no pointer, no string, no reference, and (genererally speaking) no object from the standard library (notably no std::string).

Of course, as it directly stores and load binary data representations, it will definitively not be portable across different architectures, but can be used to locally save state.

Comment: Thanks. So in reality, if it is a POD object, the member functions will not be persisted?

Comment: @jbx: Non virtual member functions are not stored in the objects themselves, so their pointer won't be persisted.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ the only difference between `struct` and `class` is their default visibility; a `struct` defaults to public, while a `class` defaults to private. Anything you can do with a `struct` can be done with a `class`. Both can have constructors, destructors, member functions, base types, virtual members, etc.

As long as a type is trivially copyable (i.e. the type has a trivial destructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignement operator and move assignment operator), or a POD type if you're using C++98, then it can be serialized to a file just as you would in C. Note that any type with virtual members, or that inherits (virtually or otherwise) from a type with virtual members is not trivially copyable.

Edit: Non-virtual member functions do not affect the layout of a type. No pointers to such functions are stored in the objects themselves.

Comment: So what happens if the class has member functions though? Won't the pointers to those member functions also get persisted (and thus I would be saving junk)?

Comment: I added some clarification on how member functions affect object layout. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Provided all member functions are stateless (no static local variables defined within member functions), there is no difference berween C++ classes and C-style structs: you serialize only the member data for each class instance.

To further clarifiy, when you write a serializer (or more commonly use a serializing library), you never store the vtable, because there is no point: only the member data are specific to an object instance, whereas the vtable is defined by the class.
Thus, the only real impact of having virtual functions is that you no longer deal with a POD-object: you cannot simply memory-dump the whole structure onto disk, and have to serialize the class instance one field after the other

Comment: This still leaves you with portability issues between different CPU architectures.

Comment: @DanielStrul I think you misunderstood the question. If a class has member functions, I do not want to persist their pointers or similar junk. Persisting a whole object will include that. Putting an internal `struct` instead of member variables, and persisting the `struct`, avoids this. I am just asking if there is any other 'typical' approach people use.